# MATLAB fileparts function and separators

Tags: string, matlab, parsing

I was wondering why MATLAB makes its predefined [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html?searchHighlight=fileparts) function drop the last `filesep` in `pathstr` output, where `pathstr` is defined through:

```
[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(filename)
```

For example, if `filename` were: `['foo',filesep,'bar',filesep,'baz','.qux']`, MATLAB returns:

```
pathstr =

foo/bar 

name =

baz

ext = 

.qux
```

Is there a reason, for which I'm not realizing, why it should drop this last `filesep`?

Comment: `fileparts` just behaves consistent other functions like `pwd`, `path` or `genpath`, no tailing slash is used for any directory.

Comment: I'm guessing that only The MathWorks could answer this. It may have something to do with [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) – see [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/basename.html) and [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html) (Section A.4.12).

Comment: I just didn't think it should be considered a "tailing" slash when there's an actual file name involved. I found it a bit unnatural that `[pathstr,name,ext]` is not the actual path to the file... I guess it's just details, though...